# Is there an English name for "expansion bar"?

Tags: word-request

Is there an English word for a bar, which can be mounted between two surfaces using the "mechanically generated" tension (I guess that there is a screw)? Let's say that it works using "reversed vice tool" rule. I am attaching an example image of it. In my language (Polish) it is "drążek rozporowy". PS: I am interested in mounting it and then, mounting something to it, rather that transport purposes.

[image: "expansion bar"]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks a bit like a 'jack post', 'telepost', 'adjustable steel shoring post', 'adjustable steel column (or prop)', etc. A steel bar or rod that can be adjusted for length, usually coarsely using a pin in a selected hole, and then finely using a screw mechanism. They are often used in the construction trades for temporary support of e.g. ceilings, walls (vertical) and trenches (horizontal). In Britain, and certain other countries (I believe in Australia and New Zealand) they are very commonly called 'Acrow props', even though not all that you can buy or hire are made by the Acrow company.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I've always called these "[acrow props](https://www.girtby.com/blog/2016/10/26/creation-of-the-acrow-prop)" or "acrows" for short, though that might be a trade name.

Comment: Acrow with a capital A. It's really a trade name for one brand of adjustable prop, introduced by the UK Acrow company in 1935, but it's like calling all paper tissues 'Kleenex' or all vacuum cleaners 'Hoover'. The name gets used for all of them.